# What does $S$ mean in this standard deviation estimate

Tags: notation

What does $S$ mean in estimates like
$$s^2 = \frac{S(x_1^2)}{n} - \left(\frac{S(x_1)}{n}\right)^2
= \frac{S(x_1^2)}{n} - \frac{S(x_1^2)}{n} - 2\frac{S(x_1 x_2)}{n^2}$$
(for context look "The probable error of a mean", Student, Biometrica)

And what does it mean in
$$\sigma_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2} S(|x-\overline x|)$$
$$\sigma_2 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} S(x-\overline x)^2}$$
(look Fisher, "One the Mathematical Foundations of Theoretical Statistics")

Comment: Summation, $\sum$. I imagine Greek letters used to give trouble for the typesetters.

Comment: And can I ask also to expand one of the latter two? Especially the one with $pi/2$ -- I have no clue where it comes from

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question & give more context.

Comment: $$\sigma_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2} S(|x-\overline x|)$$ becomes $$\sigma_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n(|x_i-\overline x|)$$ upon the substitutions $S\to\sum_{i=1}^n$ and $x\to x_i$. One might even present this formula as $$\sigma_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{x}(|x-\overline x|)$$ with the implicit understanding that $x$ ranges over a given (multi)set of data, where the *only* change has been $S\to\sum_x$. (@Scortchi I expect anyone with a "$\pi$" in their font would also have a "$\Sigma$": it wasn't a typesetting issue, just common notation.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I expected (just needed to be sure). Only this $pi/2$ is remaining. Will think of it and maybe ask in separate question

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$ is the mean of the absolute value of a   $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variate.